# Invalid Column Name in union clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a fixed value `'ALLE'` to my column with a union clause, but I get an error:

> Invalid column name BoltPattern

at my `order by` clause

How exactly do I do this?

```
SELECT 'ALLE' 
UNION 
SELECT BoltPattern
FROM [OminiTire].[Data].[WheelData]
WHERE BoltPattern IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY BoltPattern
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN BoltPattern = 'ALLE' 
          THEN 1 
       ELSE 2 
    END, BoltPattern
```

Comment: what's the desired result here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a subquery . . . and `union all`:

```
SELECT BoltPattern
FROM ((SELECT 'ALLE' as BoltPattern, 1 as ord) 
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT DISTINCT BoltPattern, 2 as ord
       FROM [OminiTire].[Data].[WheelData]
       WHERE BoltPattern is not null
      )
     ) x
ORDER BY ord, BoltPattern;
```

Notes:

- `UNION` incurs overhead to remove duplicates.  `UNION ALL` does not.
- I find `SELECT DISTINCT` to be more succinct than using the `GROUP BY`.
- The subquery allows you to define the explicit ordering -- easier to maintain (in my opinion) than a complicated `CASE` expression.

Comment: I tend to prefer CTEs over sub-queries like that... easier to read and maintain, exact same performance.

Comment: @pmbAustin . . . Although this is true in SQL Server, it is not true in all databases.  Some databases are more likely to materializes CTEs than subqueries.